# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named XXX

Tags: python

This is a part my workspace directory structure:

```py
workspace
+-- .vscode
    +-- launch.json
+-- main
    +-- __init__.py
    +-- main.py
+-- utils
    +-- __init__.py
    +-- func.py
    +-- func2.py
```

In func.py I wrote:

```py
import sys
sys.path.append('.')

from func2 import func2

def func1():
    ...
    func2()
    ...
    return ...
```

And in main.py I wrote:

```py
import sys
sys.path.append('.')

from utils.func import func1
```

When executing main.py, vscode throws an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "...\workspace\main\main.py", line 4, in <module>
    from utils.func import func1
  File "...\workspace\utils\func1.py", line 4, in <module>
    from func2 import func2
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'func2'
```

I tried calling func1 inside file func.py and run that file, it worked perfectly.
Why can't I call it in main.py ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an edit for your files (notice when executing `main.py` all paths are relative to that):

**func2.py**

```py
import sys
sys.path.append('.')

def func2():
    print('Here is...\n')
```

**func.py**

```py
import sys
sys.path.append('.')

from utils.func2 import func2    # The change is here; use the path relative to main

def func1():
    func2()
    
    return 0
```

**main.py**

```py
import sys
sys.path.append('.')

from utils.func import func1

if __name__ == '__main__':
    func1()
    print('Hello World\n')
```

Answer (score 0):

According to me you are getting directory related issues. Try placing the necessary files in a same directory.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).